# Как конвертировать из NSData в NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Имеем: NSData в которй указаны данные типа:

```
<Alias>
Position1=1
Position2=2
</Alias>

<Alias>
...
</Alias>
```

Вопрос: Как эти данные перевести в NSDictionary, где Alias будет key, а Position соответственно значением.

PS: или совсем сложно, так и Position разложить на ключ и значение.

Comment: предположу, что придется парсить руками. традиционно используется json serializer примерно так: `NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];` но у вас дата не в формате.

Comment: кстати, xml парсер может это съест

Comment: Max, json не вариант, пробовал. А вот про парсер спасибо, что-то я про него забыл. Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С подачи Max Mikheyenko я покапался в xml парсерах и написал свой по аналогии со стандартным парсером NSXMLParser. И не кидайте в меня камни, за изобретение второго велосипеда :)

Спасибо. Вопрос закрыт.

Если кому-то интересно:

```
NSString *desString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:streamData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Убираем все  NSArray
NSArray *desArray = [desString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

//Вводим переменные
NSMutableDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableDictionary *subFileDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
BOOL nowStream = NO;
NSString *keyString = @"0";

for (NSString *arrayString in desArray) {
    if ([arrayString isEqualToString:@"<ALIAS>"]) {
        //Убедились, что Алиас стартовал
        nowStream = YES;
        continue;
    }
    if ([arrayString isEqualToString:@"</ALIAS>"]) {
        //финишируем сборку конкретного Алиаса
        nowStream = NO;

        //Укладываем в основной NSDictionary
        [fileDictionary setObject:subFileDictionary forKey:keyString];

        subFileDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

        NSInteger keyInt = keyString.integerValue;
        keyInt ++;
        keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", keyInt];

        continue;
    }
    if (!arrayString.length) {
        //если ничего нет, то ошибка. Я просто "иду дальше"
        continue;
    }
    if (nowStream) {
        //раскладываем Position и укладываем в подNSDictionary
        NSArray *tempArray = [arrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [subFileDictionary setObject:tempArray[1] forKey:tempArray[0]];
    }
}
```